# Find cause of diode destruction from destroyed diode itself

Tags: diodes, pn-junction, reverse-breakdown

Is it possible to find the cause of power diode destruction, ie. if it was destroyed through:

1. reverse overvoltage spike (reverse breakdown and subsequent thermal destruction due to reverse overcurrent)
2. forward overcurrent (thermal destruction due to forward overcurrent)

**But only by inspecting the destroyed diode itself?**

Electrically it always had zero resistance between anode and cathode so far, so I mean some mechanical (destructive) way.

I know that there are ways such as X-rays or electron microscope to inspect  details of the destroyed P-N structure but these means I don't have at hand.

So I mean some less sophisticated means, such as to slowly decompose the diode package (slow grinding) and viewing the chip with normal microscope?

I also mean some common way, which does not heavily depend on diode type. The destroyed diodes I would like to inspect are SiC schottky IDH06G65C6 from Infineon.

Comment: I am not sure there is a lot you can do on a fried diode. On an IC which suffers from a pin malfunction or for which the die is partially damaged, it is often possible to decapsulate the part and inspect the die. It can be done via X-rays or chemical decap. Layer peeling is also possible but it is extremely costly and done in very crucial cases. However, on a fried IC, there is nothing you can do beside confirming the charcoal presence in the package : | Did your diode peacefully pass out or it went through a loud noise, probably indicating the die is fried inside?

Comment: @Verbal Kint: Mostly quite a loud noise or hiss. I silently assumed there would be little or no ways but I just asked, no one knows everything. Perhaps the size of burned area would indicate the destruction type (reverse breakdown - bigger impact than just 'forward breakdown')?

Comment: Re, "Electrically it always had zero resistance between anode and cathode..." A forward biased semiconductor rectifier will drop around 0.4-ish Volts (Schottky barrier diode) or 0.7-ish Volts (ordinary silicon rectifier); and it will dissipate power according to _P=IV_.  So, for example, if you pull ten Amperes through a silicon rectifier, it's going to dissipate around seven Watts, and it will burn up if it doesn't have an adequate heat sink.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I think the OP meant that once the diode was destroyed it had zero resistance.

Comment: Zero resistance in both directions is a shorted diode. Cause could be over voltage or current spike. A crack in the body of the diode means it cooked from over current until it shorted out.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, maybe.

Your choices seem to be between a very short transient and a longer-term overstressing. A short transient will typically produce arc/burn marks and other indications of localized damage. Long-term overheating will simply cause joint (usually solder) failure, and possibly large areas of discoloration.

Once the package has started to get into the act and start burning, this will generally obscure the potential differences, so good luck. If you've got a glass package, this will give you the best chance. If it's epoxy, you'll have a much tougher time.

Answer (score 0):

For my case it was ad 2, ie. overcurrent. But I've finally used another means to find the cause of diode destruction, not decomposing/inspecting the fried diode.

My opinion is that the cause cannot be found from the fried diode itself, at least not easily, ie. without knowing its internal structure and without some sophisticated means like I mentioned above.

It seems that only the diode manufacturer could do that, if at all.

If you encounter similar problem then I recommend you also find another way to find the cause. Use SPICE simulations, various exclusion methods, scope capture etc.